# MySQL SELECT range based on round to an appropriate power of 10

Tags: mysql

I use MySQL and I want to select value(DECIMAL) in this case is salary range.

I want to set the salary range based on **rounding to an appropriate power of 10** of the input variable.

For example:

For input 100000 i want to select `value > 100000 AND value < 199999`

For input 20000 i want to select `value > 20000 AND value < 29999`

for input 12345 i want to select `value > 10000 AND value < 19999`

For input 1000 i want to select `value > 1000 AND value < 1999`

How to achieve this (MySQL only)?

Comment: @A_nagpal after editing the question, is clear to understand it, and IMO is a very good question, should +1 :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this code working, this produces for

salary 100000 the values 100000 and 199999

salary 20000 the values 20000 and 29999

salary 23456 the values 20000 and 29999

see it on sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/46326

```
SET @THE_SALARY = 100000;

SELECT FLOOR((@THE_SALARY / POW(10,CEIL(LOG10((@THE_SALARY)+1))-1)))*POW(10,CEIL(LOG10((@THE_SALARY)+1))-1), FLOOR((@THE_SALARY / POW(10,CEIL(LOG10((@THE_SALARY)+1))-1))+1)*POW(10,CEIL(LOG10((@THE_SALARY)+1))-1)-1
```

from this you can do:

```
SET @THE_SALARY = 12345;
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE salary > FLOOR((@THE_SALARY / POW(10,CEIL(LOG10((@THE_SALARY)+1))-1)))*POW(10,CEIL(LOG10((@THE_SALARY)+1))-1) AND salary < FLOOR((@THE_SALARY / POW(10,CEIL(LOG10((@THE_SALARY)+1))-1))+1)*POW(10,CEIL(LOG10((@THE_SALARY)+1))-1)-1
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding from your question.

For input = 152,345

```
       select * from TableName where value<19999 and value>10000
```

For input = 152,345

```
       select * from TableName where value<29999 and value>20000
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `value` 


 BETWEEN value < 199,999 AND value > 100,000
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value < '199,999' AND `value > '100,000'
```